# "You are creating QApplication before calling UIApplicationMain" error on iOS

Tags: ios, qt

When I create a QtWidgets application, select iphonesimulator-clang Qt5.3, and run the app in debug mode on the iOS simulator I get the error below. I am not adding any code; just running the Qt Creator template code.

"Error: You are creating QApplication before calling UIApplicationMain.
 If you are writing a native iOS application, and only want to use Qt for
 parts of the application, a good place to create QApplication is from within
 'applicationDidFinishLaunching' inside your UIApplication delegate.”

I have Qt5.3.1 (installed using the online installer) and Xcode 5.1.1.

Running the provided Calculator Example on the iOS simulator works fine without the error.

Comment: There is no "auto generated" code, it's just a template that came with Qt Creator. Those templates are often sub-par. Copy a simple example instead, then remove the functionality and you'll have a decent template to start with.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That works. Still, I am interested in knowing why i get the error. Googled but could not find what i was looking for. So if you have any pointers that would be appreciated...

Comment: After some more searching i found a workaround here http://www.sheim.net/wordpress/computer/tipps-und-tricks/

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45508043/qt-ios-linker-error-entry-point-main-undefined for an updated fix for this issue

Answer (score 4):

Just in case the solution decided to disappear elsewhere: the fix is to change the signature of the main function.

```
#if defined(Q_OS_IOS)
extern "C" int qtmn(int argc, char **argv)
#else
int main(int argc, char **argv)
#endif
{
  ...
}
```